# AlertDialog: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

When I press the "Choose Photo" button, the AlertDialog seems to cancel out and I get the following message in the logcat: `Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed`

This was literally working last night and I don't recall making any changes pertaining to this function. Please help.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder cameraChoice = new AlertDialog.Builder(Person2Screen.this);
    cameraChoice.setTitle("Take/choose new photo");
    cameraChoice.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (options[which].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //savePicture(cameraIntent);
                if(id.equals(HAPPY_ID2))
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO);
                if(id.equals(SURPRISED_ID2))
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO);
                if(id.equals(AFRAID_ID2))
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO);
                if(id.equals(UPSET_ID2))
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO);
                if(id.equals(SAD_ID2))
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO);
            } else if (options[which].equals("Choose Photo")) {
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    if(id.equals(HAPPY_ID2))
                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO);
                    else if(id.equals(SURPRISED_ID2))
                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO);
                    else if(id.equals(AFRAID_ID2))
                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO);
                    else if(id.equals(UPSET_ID2))
                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO);
                    else if(id.equals(SAD_ID2))
                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO);
            } else if (options[which].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    final CharSequence[] pictureNumbers = {"Picture 1", "Picture 2", "Picture 3", "Reinforcer"};
    AlertDialog.Builder selectPhotoNumber = new AlertDialog.Builder(Person2Screen.this);
    selectPhotoNumber.setTitle("Which picture would you like to set/change?");
    selectPhotoNumber.setItems(pictureNumbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (pictureNumbers[which].equals("Picture 1")) {
                index = 1;
                cameraChoice.show();
            } else if (pictureNumbers[which].equals("Picture 2")) {
                index = 2;
                cameraChoice.show();
            } else if (pictureNumbers[which].equals("Picture 3")) {
                index = 3;
                cameraChoice.show();
            } else if (pictureNumbers[which].equals("Reinforcer")) {
                index = 4;
                cameraChoice.show();
            }
        }
    });
    selectPhotoNumber.show();
}
```

Comment: Try calling `return` right after `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: @Shaishav Didn't work :(

Comment: It isn't really crashing in mine. If you're using Instant Run, delete the app manually and retry. Btw, currently both of your `requestCode` are same.

Comment: @Shaishav uninstalling manually didn't work. I've added code to give more context for the AlertDialog. I call one from the other. All other button functionalities are working just fine; just not the "Choose Picture" one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've have noticed this way too earlier but, I guess you posted your earlier code correctly. The current issue is that we are trying to match `"Choose from Gallery"` with `"Choose Photo"` which would always be `false`. So, we need to correct that. I also refactored your code a bit:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() { 
    final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose Photo", "Cancel"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder cameraChoice = new AlertDialog.Builder(Person2Screen.this);
    cameraChoice.setTitle("Take/choose new photo");
    cameraChoice.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (options[which].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                Intent intent;
                int requestCode;

                if (options[which].equals("Take Photo")) {
                     intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                } else { // from doc
                     intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                }

                switch (id) {
                     case HAPPY_ID2:
                         requestCode = REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO;
                         break;
                     case SURPRISED_ID2:
                         requestCode = REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO;
                         break;
                     case AFRAID_ID2:
                         requestCode = REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO;
                         break;
                     case UPSET_ID2:
                         requestCode = REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO;
                         break;
                     default:
                         requestCode = REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO;
                         break;
                }

                startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
            }
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Unbelievable. Thanks for catching that and for the refactor; will be using this!

Comment: @ImagineThat Cool...regarding your edit, we already have the `REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO`...so, shouldn't the last one be SAD?